# Как использовать EVENT_AFTER_LOGIN в yii2

Tags: yii2

Как использовать `EVENT_AFTER_LOGIN` в `yii2`?

`EVENT_AFTER_LOGIN` - это константа.

**Вопрос**: как с её помощью можно фиксировать время входа в систему пользователя?

**Приложение к вопросу:** зачем нам в этом случаи нужны какие-то подобные события, когда мы можем записывать время входа пользователя, из `класса User метода public static function findIdentity`?

Вот что написано, но примера никакого не показано как использовать это событие .

> Вы можете использовать эти события для реализации функции аудита
>   входа, статистике онлайн пользователей. Для примера, в обработчике для
>   EVENT_AFTER_LOGIN, вы можете сделать запись о времени и IP адресе
>   входа в таблицу user.
>
> А ну и конечно да, EVENT_AFTER_LOGIN срабатывает только при успешном
>   входе, это тоже самое есле бы мы вставили в метод Login() наш метод
>   записи в БД дату. Вообщем, не понятно, зачем это нужно.

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский А ну и конечно да, `EVENT_AFTER_LOGIN` срабатывает только при успешном входе, это тоже самое есле бы мы вставили в метод Login() наш метод записи в БД дату. Вообщем, не понятно, зачем это нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос.

**как использовать это событие**

ну к примеру вы можете делать что то типа

```
if($model->save()){
  $model->trigger(User::EVENT_AFTER_LOGIN); 
}
```

то есть инициировать событие некого виртуального логина,что может быть применимо скажем когда вы делаете псевдо-авторизацию через какого нибудь посредника.Ну к примеру - смысл в том что события инициируются там где выгодно и нужно нам.
или использовать можно так:

```
$foo->on(НАПРИМЕР_НАСЛЕДОВАННЫЙ_ОТ_USER_КЛАСС::EVENT_AFTER_LOGIN, function ($event) {
    // логика обработки события логина
});
```

Если интересует почему использовано константа,то вот что сказано в руководстве:

> Желательно для обозначения имен событий использовать константы класса.
>   В предыдущем примере константа EVENT_HELLO обозначает событие hello. У
>   такого подхода три преимущества. Во-первых, исключаются опечатки.
>   Во-вторых, для событий работает автозавершение в различных средах
>   разработки. В-третьих, чтобы узнать, какие события поддерживаются
>   классом, достаточно проверить константы, объявленные в нем.

Вообще подробно все это тут
[https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/concept-events.md#Обработчики-событий-на-уровне-класса-](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/concept-events.md#%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-)